# Global optima on constraints

Tags: calculus, optimization

Suppose I am finding the local and global optima of $f(x,y)$ on $g(x,y)=c$ and the constraint set is *not compact*. I understand that Lagrange multiplier method can be used to find the *local* optima (if any), but how to find global optima on the constraint set?

One possible way would be to substitute the constraint into the objective and find the unconstrained optima, but is there a method that works even if such a substitution is not possible?

Another way to phrase this question is, how do I know if the critical point obtained by solving Lagrange first-order conditions is a global optimum? I know that one can use the bordered Hessian to find out if it is maximum or minimum, but from what I understand, that detects only local optima.

Comment: A commonly used criterion is convexity.

Comment: But that's only a sufficient condition, not necessary.